# Break while loop on condition changed by action listener

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop, actionlistener, break

I have made a server in Java and implemented a GUI for it. On the GUI there are two buttons - 'Allow' and 'Reject' connections. When 'Allow' is clicked the boolen value 'AllowConnections' is set to true and for 'Reject' it is set to false.

Basically the program will initialise the gui and the actionlisteners then if AllowConnections is true a socket will be opened and allow a client to connect to it. I am wanting to be able to click 'Reject' and it kick the user off the socket. The problem is that I cannot break out of the loop which constantly gets the incoming messages as it will pause and wait for a user to connect or for a user to send a message. This is shown bellow:

server class:

```
boolean loop = true;

while (loop) {

    if (allowConnections == true) {
        remote.commands();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("reject");
    }

}
```

remote class:

```
public static void commands() {

    try {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
        System.out.println("open");

        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        connected = true;

        System.out.println("connected");
        BufferedReader clientMessage = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String input;

        while (connected) {

            input = clientMessage.readLine();
            System.out.println(input);

            // do commands

        }

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In the code above the program will pause and wait for a user to connect (line: 8) and also wait for a user to send a message (line: 18) which means I cannot just put a if(!allowConnections){break;} condition statement in to break the loop.

Any ideas on how I would break this loop as the condition changes (sort of like a while loop that constantly checks conditions) or how I could rewrite this to include the feature I need?

Comment: You can close the client socket and/or the server socket

Comment: @Titus This would close the socket but wouldn't the program still be waiting for data from **accept** and **readLine** which it would never get as the socket is now closed, or would it throw an IOException after a few seconds?

Comment: No, closing the client socket will cause the `readLine()` method to throw an exception and closing the server socket will cause `accept()` to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Make *allowConnections* **static** and public (or use a getter), then you can check it inside *commands()* method.

EDIT: Start a new thread which checks if *allowConnections* has changed and call _ serverSocket.close()_ in case it change the state.

Comment: allowConnections is already public and static - that is not the issue. The issue is with **accept** and **readLine** pausing all processes until they have been executed (a client has connected to the socket or a message has come through on the socket). I was wanting to know if an actionlistener (as they run simultaneously to accept and readLine) could break the while loop as a condition could not be checked as accept and readLine are being processed.

Answer (score 1):

`ServerSocket` has method `setSoTimeout`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

This can be used to avoid `accept` blocking infinite. As the documentation states, if the time has been passed without a connection it will throw a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

Comment: Yes but I would like to be able to run the application at start-up and run it in background so that the user can connect whenever they want so a time-out wouldn't help as they could connect straight from boot-up or never. Until I find a solution I am going to make the reject button restart the application killing any processes. Thank you for your help though.